# How can I link Rosaria with Gazebo ? (Pioneer 3DX)

Tags: ros, gazebo, pioneer-3dx, aria, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I've just recently begun to work on a pioneer P3DX. Before trying to get it moving, I wanted to try it on a simulator.
I've run Aria with MobileSim fairly easily with the examples. So did I with RosAria and MobileSim following the tutorial and this : https://github.com/pengtang/rosaria_client

But when it comes to Gazebo and RosAria, I'm lost. I made a P3DX move with https://github.com/SD-Robot-Vision/PioneerModel and https://github.com/SD-Robot-Vision/p3dx_mover, but it's with ROS.
And since I ultimately want my robot moving in real life, I'm lost as how to get the RosAria example work on Gazebo. (Because i want the same code both working on Gazebo and on the P3DX)

And  since I still don't understand all of this, even when reading this post about the exact same problem :
http://answers.ros.org/question/257057/using-gazebo-simulator-with-rosaria/
I'd wanted to know if someone could perhaps clarify it / help me on this.

I also found this, which pretty much is the same problem as mine :
http://answers.ros.org/question/215815/using-gazebo-simulator-with-pioneer3dx-model/
but there was no answers as of today.

I've tried to be as clear as possible, sorry if I still sound confusing.

Hdifsttar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261647/how-can-i-link-rosaria-with-gazebo-?-(pioneer-3dx)/) by [Hdifsttar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30367/hdifsttar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosaria` can only communicate with either the Pioneer robot, or MobileSim which emulates the Pioneer robot.  To use Gazebo, set up your launch configuration such that your client nodes connect to Gazebo's ROS interface rather than `rosaria`.  Gazebo's `libgazebo_ros_diff_drive` plugin implements a differential drive controller with a similar ROS interface as `rosaria` (i.e. `cmd_vel`, `odom` topics, `base_link`, etc.).  If you want to try the Gazebo and URDF configuration from https://github.com/MobileRobots/amr-ros-config and provide any feedback (via github or the ros-sig-pioneer mailing list), that would be very helpful for improving it.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hdifsttar](https://answers.ros.org/users/30367/hdifsttar/) on 2017-05-18**:
Thanks Reed, I get it now.